# Why would a glyph be missing between systems?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am writing a simple web application which I develop on Windows 10 but which will be ultimately displayed on a linux instance (a Raspberry Pi).

There is one glyph missing between these two instances, despite the font being explicitly loaded in my CSS definitions:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800');
.display {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  This is a right arrow: ⇢
  <br> This is a down arrow: ⭭
</div>
```

The result of the above should be

[image]

This is indeed the case on my development environment (Windows 10) but the same application started on the Rpi **does show the "right" arrow, but not the "down" one**. It is replaced by a rectangle with a code (the down arrow is supposed to be between the `8:18`and the `8:43`):

[image]

**Since it works in one place and not in the other, it means that the glyph is missing. But missing where?**

I am mostly confused because I load a fond and then make use of it, so it is present in both places, displayed by a standard web browser. Where does the OS comes into play here?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847665/how-do-browsers-deal-with-tofu-characters/56849538#56849538
If you inspect the element and look at the computed fonts, for me it shows that the right arrow is rendered in `Cambria Math` and the down arrow in `Segoe UI`. Open Sans only contains the letters, for other symbols another local font is used, so probably your Rpi is missing the font `Segoe UI` or another font with a down arrow.

Comment: @elveti: thank you, this is will be it. I did not realize that substitute fonts are computes - I thought that a glyph is either present in the font and rendered, or not present and not rendered at all. I will mark my question as duplicate and upvote your answer over there. Thanks again.